# Jquery positioning, make the level 2 of the menu always adjust to level 1's ending pixel

Tags: jquery

Basicly I got a 2 level menu that has the property of position fixed of the level 1 and 2.

level 1 can change in height when the menu breaks. And I somehow want level 2 to always end up JUST below the level 1. So if level 1 has position fixed; top:0; and height:100px; I want level two to have position fixed; top:100px; And somehow watch if level 1 increases in height to have level 2 follow its positioning.

Any chance you could help me? I'm close to my deadline :'(

Comment: Will you post some code please?

Comment: @SimplePsycho Well I got no jquery code as it is now, nothing has worked haha. Too bad on jquery. 

But..

.level1{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
.level2{
position:fixed;
top: 100px;
}

I want to have some jquery to adjust the position of the level 2 if height if level 1 changes

Comment: @SimplePsycho http://generatedesignstaging.com/safari/safaris/value-safaris/the-beast-retreat/

Comment: Aah that's the site you're building off eh? Which menu are you talking about? The one when you click the top-right button thing?

Comment: @SimplePsycho I want the second level menu to always follow the height of the level one top menu. So if Height is 80px on level 1 (where the logo is in) the level 2 menu should be 80px from top. If it gets larger, second menu should follow. You understand?

Comment: make a variable that gets the height of the level1 menu - `var firstHeight = $('.level1').height();` - then set `$('.level2').css('top',firstHeight);` - that's the way to go... you can do it both on load and on `window.resize()` event

Comment: @MiaSno 

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 var firstHeight = jQuery('.main-header').height();
 jQuery('.sub-menu').css('top',firstHeight);
});

Did not work :( Can it be because the .main-header got no fixed height?

Comment: @MiaSno Yeah console.log(firstHeight); gives me null :S

Comment: @MiaSno I'm sorry, it worked, kind off but didnt give me the right height. I added .outerHeight(true) to include margins and paddings, but it's still off....

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    var firstHeight = jQuery('#main-header').height() + 10;
    jQuery('.sub-menu').css('top',firstHeight);

    jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
       var firstHeight = jQuery('#main-header').height() + 10;
       jQuery('.sub-menu').css('top',firstHeight);
    });

});
```